# Can a script run when someone edits their form entry with Google Forms?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, form-submit

I have an email notification script set up, so that when you fill out a Google form, it emails the information to the user's address. The problem is that the message is only sent when you first complete the form. If you go back and edit your entry via the edit link, it does not resend the message.

I've tried setting the triggers to run the script From spreadsheet, On change, and On edit, and On form submit. From what I can see, if the script is set to run on submit, that should cover any edits, right? It's still a form submit. Is there anything that blocks the message from being resent? If so, is there a way to turn that off?

Here is my script:

```
function emailToUser(e) {
  var userChurch = e.values[1];
  var userEmail = e.values[198];
  var userDistrict = e.values[3];
  var userChild = e.values[4];
  var userComm = e.values[12];
  var userBoard = e.values[20];
  var subject = "Form submitted";
  var message = "Thank you, " + userChurch + " for your participation.\n\nYou have entered the following information:\nDistrict: " + userDistrict + "\nChildren's Ministires: " + userChild + "\nCommunications Coordinator:" + userComm + "\nCouncil Board Chair: " + userBoard;


  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the script is attached to the spreadsheet that the form records data to then editing the form response does not trigger the script.
If you attach the script to the form itself, then it will trigger during the edit response process